# save and load data from .txt to the right texbox

Tags: c#, file, textbox, load, save

I want to use a `.txt` file instead of a XML and I want to keep using the `WriteAllLineS`/`WriteAllText` and `ReadAllLines`/`ReadAllText`. 
I have two text boxes 1 & 2 and next to them is a "save" and "load" button - one for each textbox.

My code so far replicates the data from the first box into the second one. Here is the listing:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 string fileName = "Cache/textBoxdata.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
private void load1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
      textBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    }

 private void Save1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, textBox1.Lines);
     }

private void load2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName); 
    }

private void save2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, textBox2.Lines);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to write text in the two text boxes, click the "save" button - this should write entered text to the file. Then, once I reopen the app click the "load" button, my data should be loaded from the file and appear in the text box.

At the moment my first text box works. Second text box shows what I wrote in the first one - not the second one.

Comment: a question would help

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have two save/load buttons? Your question is about saving/loading both textboxes at once. So you need only one button for each operation.

To save/load the lines of a textbox into/from a file you can use `WriteAllLines` and `ReadAllLines` as you already do. Since you want to have only one file you need to know where the lines for the first textbox end and the second begins. The easiest way to do so is to write the number of lines into the file:

```
private void SaveTextboxes()
{
    List<string> linesToSave = new List<string>();

    linesToSave.Add(textBox1.Lines.Length.ToString());
    linesToSave.AddRange(textBox1.Lines);

    linesToSave.Add(textBox2.Lines.Length.ToString());
    linesToSave.AddRange(textBox2.Lines);

    File.WriteAllLines(filename, linesToSave);
}

private void LoadTextboxes()
{
    string[] loadedLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    int index = 0;

    int n = int.Parse(loadedLines[index]);
    string[] lines = new string[n];
    Array.Copy(loadedLines, index + 1, lines, 0, n);
    textBox1.Lines = lines;

    index += n + 1;

    n = int.Parse(loadedLines[index]);
    lines = new string[n];
    Array.Copy(loadedLines, index + 1, lines, 0, n);
    textBox2.Lines = lines;
}
```

If you add more textboxes you can repeat this for the desired number of textboxes. Build an array of the textboxes and loop through it.

If you really want to have separate save/load buttons for each textbox this might be a bit more confusing since you only want to overwrite a part of the text. Basically this means that on save you first read the whole file into two separate arrays and then write them back with the respective array being replaced by the new text.

Comment: thanks this works perfectly going to see if i can add all my other textboxes now

Comment: I have 19 textboxes in total and it now has an error message saying Index was outside the bounds of the array

Answer (score 0):

of course is the text in the textbox the same after loading - you are using the same file ...

you can save the content into two different files, then it should work

Comment: yeah I want the same text for what I write in the each textbox not the same thing in everyone in my example im working on now theres two textboxes. I typed in Hi in the first one and bye n the second one when I go to reload they both say Hi

Comment: yes, because both text boxes save their content into the single file Cache/textBoxdata.txt

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.